# .htaccess can not redirect URL without extension

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I'm having some URLs (linked from outside) which do not have an extension, e.g

```
www.example.com/main
```

Originally there were files `main.htm` and `main.html` in the server's root.

However, an

```
RewriteRule ^main$ main.html [L,R=301]
```

does not work.

There is no folder `main/` nor a file named `main` in the server root.

There are other entries in the `.htaccess` file which do work, so I'm sure the RewriteMod is active and working. I also have rewrite rules for typos (a link to `www.example.com/xyz)` that can be redirected.

```
RewriteRule ^xyz\)$ xyz/index.html [L,R=301]
```

The interesting thing is that the `www.example.com/main` URL appears unaltered in the browser (the URL in the browser bar doesn't change (as it does with a redirect)) but the page appears with the content of the file `main.de.html`. If I create a file named `main.da.html` it appears with that content (but only after an apache restart).

I can not figure out how it gets there or how to redirect it to `main.html`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable MutliViews at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

MultiViews (part of mod_negotiation) will ordinarily *search* for physical files that match `main` (in this case) as a basename (and would respond with an appropriate mime-type). This happens *before* mod_rewrite. So, if you had a file called `main.de.html`, this will be served as an internal subrequest (no redirect) before mod_rewrite has had a chance to process.

> (but only after an apache restart).

This isn't something that would ordinarily require an Apache restart. Although it's possible that there is some caching going on. (?)

> ```
> RewriteRule ^main$ main.html [L,R=301]
> ```

Aside: This is unlikely to be valid as an external redirect, unless you have an existing `RewriteBase` directive (I assume you must have)? Otherwise you should prefix the *substitution* with a slash. ie. `/main.html` (if the file is in the document root).

> www.example.com/main URL appears unaltered in the browser

If MulitViews is not the problem, then it could be that the directive is in the wrong place in the config file and other directives are perhaps conflicting. We would need to see your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Correct (yes, there is RewriteBase / futher up in the file.  To make sure it's nothing conflicting, I had tried without the entire .htaccess file previously, but forgot to mention it).